# can I do parent other object to other object masked by mask tracker?

Tags: video, after-effects, production

can I put information of mask tracker to another object's position??

or

can I do parent other object to other object masked by mask tracker??

Answer (score 0):

So that's two questions.

1: You sure can _put information of mask tracker to another object's position.

what information are you talking about?

2: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** In recent versions (2018+) of AE you can access the mask vertices through expressions using the `points()` function or the `pointOnPath()` function that is available for all path objects.

The `points()` function returns an array of all the path vertices, so you need to use the square brackets to designate which member of the array you want, for example :

```
thisComp.layer("my masked layer").mask("my tracked mask 1").points(t = time)[5]
```

would give you the sixth (counting starts at zero) point on the mask, in layer coordinates (so the position is given relative to that layer). `t=time` is the default and is optional, you can set it to return the value from another time e.g. `t=time-someLayer.inpoint`.

Or to find a point along the path, not just a vertex:

```
thisComp.layer("my masked layer").mask("my tracked mask 1").pointOnPath(percentage = 0.5, t = time)
```

would return the half way point on a mask.

Tangent handles are also available for expressions.

Adobe's documentation is available [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/expression-language-reference.html#Expressionaccesstopathspointsonshapesmasksandbrushstrokesexpressionreference), should you wish to RTFM

**2.** Not quite sure what the second part of your question is asking.